# SAS: Replace rare levels in variable with new level "Other"

Tags: sas

I've got pretty big table where I want to replace rare values (for this example that have less than 10 occurancies but real case is more complicated- it might have 1000 levels while I want to have only 15). This list of possible levels might change so I don't want to hardcode anything.

My code is like:

```
%let var = Make;

    proc sql;

    create table stage1_ as
        select &var.,
               count(*) as count
        from sashelp.cars
        group by &var.
        having count >= 10 
        order by count desc

    ;
    quit;

    /* Join table with table including only top obs to replace rare
       values with "other" category */
    proc sql;
    create table stage2_ as 
        select t1.*,
                case when t2.&var. is missing then "Other_&var." else t1.&var. end as &var._new
        from sashelp.cars t1 left join 
             stage1_ t2 on t1.&var. = t2.&var.
    ;
    quit;

    /* Drop old variable and rename the new as old */
    data result;
        set stage2_(drop= &var.);
        rename &var._new=&var.;
    run;
```

It works, but unfortunately it is not very officient as it needs to make a join for each variable (in real case I am doing it in loop).
Is there a better way to do it? Maybe some smart replace function?

Thanks!!

Comment: For the case of a character variable, say `pqr` being *mapped* to `pqr_new`, a **not** 10-most frequent (your definition of *rare*) value of `pqr` would be changed to the literal `"Other_pqr"`.  For the case of a numeric variable, say `xyz` being *mapped* to `xyz_new`, what literal value would be used to indicate otherness for it's rare numeric values?

Comment: The number of levels isn't really a problem, the messiness would be more from the number of variables.  How many variables are you dealing with ? Do you want to *map* all the variables automatically, or just ones you specify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to change the actual data values.  Instead consider creating a custom format for each variable that will map the rare values to an 'Other' category.

The `FREQ` procedure ODS can be used to capture the counts and percentages of **every** variable listed into a single table.  NOTE: `Freq` `table/out=` captures only the last listed variable.  Those counts can be used to construct the format according to the 'othering' rules you want to implement.

```
data have;
  do row = 1 to 1000;
    array x x1-x10;
    do over x;
      if row < 600 
        then x = ceil(100*ranuni(123));
        else x = ceil(150*ranuni(123));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

ods output onewayfreqs=counts;

proc freq data=have ;
  table x1-x10;
run;

data count_stack;
  length name $32;
  set counts;
  array x x1-x10;
  do over x;
    name = vname(x);
    value = x;
    if value then output;
  end;
  keep name value frequency;
run;

proc sort data=count_stack;
  by name descending frequency ;
run;

data cntlin;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set count_stack;
    by name;
    length fmtname $32;
    fmtname = trim(name)||'top';
    start = value;
    label = cats(value);
    if _n_ < 11 then output;
  end;
  hlo = 'O';
  label = 'Other';
  output;
run;

proc format cntlin=cntlin;
run;

ods html;

proc freq data=have;
  table x1-x10;
  format
    x1 x1top.
    x2 x2top.
    x3 x3top.
    x4 x4top.
    x5 x5top.
    x6 x6top.
    x7 x7top.
    x8 x8top.
    x9 x9top.
    x10 x10top.
  ;
run;
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I haven't been clear about the purpose of it. It was supposed to been changed for good as the data was later used for modelling purpose (in different environment - python).